# how to make root directory in version 10 or 10+

Tags: android, directory, root

This is Main Activity java class. how to create root directory in android version 10 or 10+,what should I do? Anybody suggest how to solve this problem. my friend suggested me using cursor make root folder i dont understand how to use cursor for making root directory.

```
 ibSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivEffectImage.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

                AsyncTaskExample asyncTask = new AsyncTaskExample(bitmap);
                asyncTask.execute(bitmap);
            }

        });
```

This is AysncTask class which implements MainActivity.java in doInBackground method try to create root folder but I was failed.

```
  private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap bitmapVar;

        public AsyncTaskExample(Bitmap bitmapVar) {
            this.bitmapVar = bitmapVar;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Image_OverLay.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while image in downloading");
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SaveImage");

            dir.mkdir();

            String file = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outfile = new File(dir, file);

            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
                bitmapVar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(Image_OverLay.this, new String[]{
                    outfile.toString()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String s, Uri uri) {

                }
            });
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            super.onPostExecute(unused);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(Image_OverLay.this, "image is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Image_OverLay.this, Get_Effect_Image.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A big misconception in your post-   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); is not the SD card.  Its a different Android concept called external storage.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` That IS the root directory. You cannot/neednot create it as it is always there. Please rephrase your post.

Comment: Only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call it than check return value as it might fail to create the directory. In that case stop/return. Adapt your code please.

Comment: Only call the media scanner if all went well. Not after exceptions. Update your code please.

Comment: `return null;` Dont always return null. Return a string with a message so in onPostExecute you know what happened.

Comment: Did you request legacy external storage in manifest fule? As that is special for Android Q devices.

Comment: yes i added request legacy true